# Node.js exports module not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very beginner to node.js, I found a tutorial to learn. while I learn I used this code to run my server it works fine:

code :

```
var http = require ("http");

http.createServer (function (request, response) {

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hellow world! I written my first server side code!"); //browser responding
    response.end();

} ).listen(8888);
```

But while I tried to export the server like this,

```
var http = require("http");

function start() {

    function onRequest(request, response) {
        console.log("Request received.");
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("Hello World");
        response.end();
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server has started.");

}

exports.start = start; // the export module not work?
```

and i am getting an error in browser like this:

```
Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server.
```

I am not able to start my server, and export the module any one suggest me the fix for this please?

Comment: Are you starting exported server from another module (e.g. `index.js`) like `require('./app').start()`?

Comment: I am sorry it's my fault. i didn't start the server using index.js - after i do, I works fine. thanks